# Отличие между BackGround и SRC

Tags: android, java

Почему если загрузить картинку в src то она выводиться во весь свой текущий размер. А если в BackGround, то она немного растягивается, да и  размер становиться не такой как в src. Это фишка какая то или что не пойму

Вот картинка

[image: asdd]

вверху textView bacgorund
внизу просто ImageView src

Answer (score 2):

src - это свойства ImageView. по аналогии, это фотография для рамки, потому рамка подгоняется под размер картинки.

background - это фон любого View, потому он занимает место, которое уже выделено для элемента и не больше.

Answer (score 2):

Background можно расценивать, как SRC + ScaleType=fitXY.  
Почему так - знает один только гугл.

Comment: @Gorets, @metalurgus, Я видимо не так вопрос задал))). Мне нужно в  картинку добавить текст. Тоесть в TextView добавить src. Как сделать такое? не подскажите

Comment: @ANDRO, вам надо в TextView добавить фон? Для этих задач существует nine-patch

Answer (score 0):

[@metalurgus](/users/3997/metalurgus), да все уже разобрался. Отпилил картинку на двое и 9 path сделал, после в background textview